# What's the keyboard shortcut to move between source code and debugger in RubyMine?

Tags: intellij-idea, rubymine

How do I navigate between my source code and the debugger without using the mouse?

I want to jump between home_controller.rb file and debugger window. ??

[image: http://cl.ly/image/0x3C0i2c1s0p]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the debug tool window is mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>5</kbd>). So typing that will give the debug too window focus. To return to the editor from any tool window, type <kbd>Esc</kbd>. You can also type <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>5</kbd> a second time, but that will close the debug tool window and take you to the editor.

You can modify the key map for a tool window in *File > Settings > [IDE Settings> Keymap > Main Menu > View > Tool Windows*